# Generate all base26 triplests in the fastest way

Tags: python, algorithm, base64, radix

I need to generate a list of triplets containing only uppercase English letters:

```
["AAA","AAB","AAC", ..., 'ZZZ']
```

What is the fastest way to do this in python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> from string import ascii_uppercase
>>> triplets = map(''.join, product(ascii_uppercase, repeat=3))
>>> triplets[4]
'AAE'
```